# "Display over other apps" prevents me from entering passwords

Tags: password, android-12, oneplus, overlay

The smartphone is a OnePlus Nord CE 5G, model EB2103.

Basically, when I focus a field where I'm supposed to enter a password, a system "Display over other apps" like this

[image]

takes over and overlays the original app, not allowing me to enter the password in any way.

This happened after I upgraded to Android 12.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Ua7H8pZTSWUVimFxLN7JxTYJL0YGXvd/view?usp=share_link) I've filmed what happens.

Any clue how I can solve this?

---

I've also noticed one more detail. If the app has the little eye icon to make it show the password (unlike the app in the video), I can click on that icon ***before*** focusing the password field, then when I focus it and type the passord, the annoying thing doesn't happen.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17VE5IZIJp_nTrCTaSnXVZcI5s1We2h0D/view?usp=share_link) is the video of this behavior, ***but be aware that the screen never gets full black for me; I always see what's going on while I type the password***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the logcat, **the Password Store (legacy) app (package name: `com.zeapo.pwdstore`) tried to open the "Display over other apps" permission settings.**

The relevant logcat is

```
ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION dat=package:com.zeapo.pwdstore flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$OverlaySettingsActivity mCallingUid=10278} from uid 10278
```

This has been reported on its GitHub repo, [Issue #767 - [BUG] "Display over other apps" settings panel keeps popping up.](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/issues/767). According to the developer, this is caused by the older autofill method *leveraging the accessibility service for pre-Oreo* (because the proper autofill service was [introduced in Android 8.0 Oreo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill)).

From [comment #13](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/issues/767#issuecomment-637372515) and afterward by the developer:

> @jonathf @Rio6 can you both check your accessibility services and verify if the Password Store service is still enabled?

> > Yes, it is installed and enabled.
>
> That's the problem, it shouldn't be. We don't use the accessibility service on Android Oreo and above. Try disabling it manually and I'll push a patch to prompt users automatically.

> I've updated the fix for this at [#827](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store/pull/827) to automatically disable the a11y service on Android Oreo and above so we'll be able to seamlessly resolve the problem without manual intervention.

For the solution, **disabling the accessibility service for this app should fix the issue.**

---

Note: according to [Site/app linking to the legacy Password Store](https://github.com/open-keychain/open-keychain/issues/2617), the app has been migrated from `com.zeapo.pwdstore` to `dev.msfjarvis.aps`. The renewed app is on:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/android-password-store/Android-Password-Store)
- [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.msfjarvis.aps)
- [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/dev.msfjarvis.aps/)